# How can I show that $(\|B_t\|^2-dt)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

> Let $B$ be a $d$-dimensional $(\Bbb{F}, \Bbb{P})$-Brownian motion where $\Bbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$. Then consider $X:=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}=(\|B_t\|^2-dt)_{t\geq 0}$. I want to check that it is a martingale.

To do so I need to check the following three points:

1. $\Bbb{E}(\|X_t\|)<\infty$ for all $t\geq 0$
2. $X$ is $\Bbb{F}$-adapted and measurable
3. $\Bbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)=X_s$ for all $0\leq s\leq t$.

Now let me prove the first point. Fix $t\geq 0$ then $$\begin{align}\Bbb{E}(\|X_t\|)=\Bbb{E}(\|B_t\|^2-dt)=\Bbb{E}(\|B_t\|^2)-dt=0<\infty\end{align}$$

The second point causes a problem, since I don't see how to prove adaptedness and measurability. I thought that I can take $A\in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ and show that $X^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{F}_s$ but then I struggle a bit with the measurability. Can someone explain me this?

For the third point let $0\leq s\leq t$ then $$\begin{align}\Bbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)&=\Bbb{E}(\|B_t\|^2-dt|\mathcal{F}_s)\\&=\Bbb{E}(\|B_t\|^2|\mathcal{F}_s)-dt\\&\end{align}$$ But also here I don't see further. Can someone explain me this also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_t$ is the composition of $B_t$ with the continuous map $x \mapsto \|x\|^{2}-dt$ so it is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable. $X$ has continuous paths also so it is a measuarble process. For the last part a hint is $B_t-B_s$ and $B_s$ are orthogonal in $L^{2}$: $E(\|B_t\|^{2}|\mathcal F_s)=E([\|(B_t-B_s)+B_s\|^{2}]\mathcal F_s)=E([\|(B_t-B_s)\|^{2}]\mathcal F_s)+E([\|B_s\|^{2}]\mathcal F_s)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Does I then can say that since $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, also $\|(B_t-B_s)\|^2$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$ and then I conclude  since $\Bbb{E}(\|(B_t-B_s)\|^2)=0$?

Comment: $E\|(B_t-B_s)\|^{2}$ is certainly  not $0$. Do you  know what $E\|B_{t-s}\|^{2}$ is? @Summerday

Comment: So I know that $B_{t-s}$ is a gaussuan vector with mean $0$ and variance $(t-s) I_d$

Comment: Or would it be better to say $E(\|B_{t-s}\|^2)=\sum_{k=1}^d E(|B_{t-s}^{(k)}|)$ but then how can I continue? Would it then be $E(|B_{t-s}^{(k)}|)=\int x f_{B_{t-s}^{(k)}}(x) dx$ where  $f_{B_{t-s}^{(k)}}(x)$ is the density of the normal distribution with parameter $t-s$

Comment: It is just $d(t-s)$. (Sum of $d$ terms each of which is $t-s$).

Comment: How did you do that?